# How do I suppress reversion in a Compact ChoiceSet for Adaptive Cards

Tags: typescript, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have 3 compact Choiceset fields, whose user-selected values are visibly reverted back to "Select an option" once the user clicks "Submit".
This is very annoying to users and causes confusion.
The selected values are, in actuality, still present in the card, as clicking "Submit" again submits the originally selected values.
This creates problems, as alerting a user to choices that conflict with choices in another Choiceset becomes painful, as the original choices are no longer visible on the card.
How can I suppress this unwanted reversion?
I am using dynamically created cards via the bot SDK.

Comment: Could you please share the card payload and elaborate a little on the issue?

Comment: By "payload" do you mean the content of "context.activity" on input?

Comment: "context.activity.values"?

Comment: Could you please confirm if this is what your issue is? Even after submitting the card the selected member is still there and we can submit that card again. Attaching a screenshot -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KsBW.png